Create conditional formatting in pandas dataframe column
I have created the following pandas dataframe:
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


ds = {'col1' : ['(-inf, 0.0]','(0.0, 4.0]','(4.0, 50.0]'],                                                                                                                             
      'col2' : [-0.05,0.02,0.35]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)

The dataframe looks like this:
print(df)

          col1  col2
0  (-inf, 0.0] -0.05
1   (0.0, 4.0]  0.02
2  (4.0, 50.0]  0.35

I have then defined the following function which creates a formatted table of that dataframe:
def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=10, #12.5
                     header_color='#ff0000', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                     ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
        ax.axis('off')
    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)
    mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)

    for k, cell in mpl_table._cells.items():
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
        else:
            cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors) ])
    return ax.get_figure(), ax

I apply the function to the dataframe and the resulting table looks like this:
fig,ax = render_mpl_table(df, header_columns=0, col_width=2)


I need to create a conditional formatting (similar to what happens in excel) in col2 such that the bars follow the values in that column. The resulting dataframe looks like this:

Can someone help me please?
Edit:
I meant: I need to view those conditional bars inside the table. Something like this:


df.style.bar(subset=["col2"], color=("red", "blue")).format(precision=2) ?

I don't understand. Where should I include that line of code?

On its own. df.style.bar(subset=["col2"], color=("red", "blue")).format(precision=2) will create an HTML table with the desired formatting

I have edited the question.
I meant: I need to view those conditional bars inside the table.
